# How to store the return value of webdriverObject.get_attribute("srcset") present in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a Selenium WebDriver **scraper** script in Python to **scrape** data from Instagram which will help me create a dataset for a deep learning problem. I am neither able to store the Unicode return value of `webdriverObject.get_attribute()` nor able to convert it to a string. But surprisingly, I am able to print these values.

How may I store the result into a list after converting the Unicode into a string?

Below is my code:

```
################################ import modules and set path ###############
from selenium import webdriver


path="C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
from time import sleep

################################ login into instagram #######################
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="password"]')
username.send_keys("username") #pass your username
password.send_keys("pass") #pass your password

sleep(3)

a=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._5f5mN").click()

######################################## search for a hashtag###################
inpu=raw_input("Enter the hashtag: ")
url="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+inpu+"/?hl=en"
driver.get(url)

b=[]
for i in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img"):
    b.append(i.get_attribute("srcset"))
print b
```

> Output of the above code is [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
> which is a list of blank Unicodes.

If I now change the last part of code and replace `b.append(i.get_attribute("srcset"))` by `print i.get_attribute("srcset")` then it seems to be printing the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
i.get_attribute("srcset").decode("utf-8")
```

Hope it helps you!